# Image lazy loading in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use lazy loading of images concept in my table view. My array of image rul string is ( `MSMutableArray` ) "images". How can I implement this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

It looks like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)AtableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[searchtable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(!cell)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];



        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[appSmallLogos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[appReleaseDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
   UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(your bounds);  
[cell addSubview:indicator];
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
[indicator startAnimating];


        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
     //This is what you will load lazily
        NSString *u=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:r.url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSURL *imageURL=url;
        NSData *image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:image];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
  [indicator stopAnimating];

        });
    });
cell.cellDescription.text=r.url;// this is which you want to add in first time.
```

I am not sure but try it.

Comment: can u please tell me that how can i show activity indicator till the images does not show in table view cell?

Comment: I haven't done that for table view but try out my updated answer.

Comment: i want to implement this in my gallery page which is also downloading images asynchronously like above method.

Comment: sorry it was my bug . I have updated the answer. Just tell me quickly whether is it working or not?

Comment: I want to show indicator here.   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSURL *imageURL=url;
        NSData *image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData: data];     [scroll addSubview:imageview];
  [indicator stopAnimating];

        });
    });

Comment: i want to show images in scroll view and i want to show indicator until image doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library, the library will download and cache the image asynchronously. by passing the url to it as argument

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];                                       This line is showing error with setImageWithUrl and placeholder image.

Comment: make sure you added the library to your project correctly, and do not forget to `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` where ever you want to display the image.

Comment: It's showing error when importing it. where the files exists?

Comment: it will not show error if you correctly linked the library to your project. read https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation for guide

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableCellLayout *cell = (TableCellLayout *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableCellLayout alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.cellName = [[array valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; // add a placeholder    

    NSString *imageURL = [[array valueForKey:@"imageLink"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];

    if (asynchronousImageLoader == nil){
        asynchronousImageLoader = [[AsynchronousImages alloc] init];
    }
    [asynchronousImageLoader loadImageFromURL:theURL];

    cell.cellImage = asynchronousImageLoader.image;

return cell;
}
```

I finally managed to do it setting the image with:

```
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

After the image is downloaded